# git merge: “error: cannot stat 'file': Permission denied”

Tags: git

I'm using git and I want to merge one of my branch onto the master. I did : `git merge myBranch`. I get this error :

```
error: cannot stat 'client/Maintenance/Gamme': Permission denied
error: cannot stat 'client/Maintenance/Gamme': Permission denied
Updating 6d3ccfa..a419e19
```

I try to abort with `git merge --abort` and to try again, but I still have the same error.

Is there a way to fix this or is there a way to do it differently ?

Comment: This is a permission issue, not a git one I think. Maybe the repo has been cloned into a folder which has strict file permissions?

Comment: I *think* clashes between different cases of the same name can result in permission errors on Windows (i.e. trying to create a directory `Gamme` when a file `gamme` already exists). So it *could* be that.

Comment: @evolutionxbox Indeed the repo has been cloned into a folder which has strict file permissions, but I'm logged with admin user.

Comment: are you type commands in the windows command prompt or IDE command prompt?

Comment: @KaumadieKariyawasam I am type commands in the windows command prompt

Comment: @CamilleClc If you opened some IDE , close it and try again

Comment: I tried the command with another session, and it worked perfectly... I don't understand why

Comment: Probably the file was open/locked by another program.

Comment: @MicroVirus that seems to be the most logical explanation.

Comment: Note that the line `Updating 6d3ccfa..a419e19` means that Git did not do a merge; it did a fast-forward instead. There is therefore nothing to abort.

Answer (score 1):

If you are a Linux user you can modify the Folder permissions using :

```
sudo chmod 666 your_project_folder
```

After That you can use :

```
git merge
```

because this problem related to your folder permission not to git.

I hope that this help you to resolve your issue.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not a linux user.

Comment: you are a windows user, just use powershell/git bash  and run it as an administrator

Comment: This is exactly what I did the first time, and this is where I got the error. I tried on another windows session (which has the same rights on this folder), and it worked.

Comment: great , so it's depend to  the session ?